# Можно ли как-то сделать плавное закрытие тега details

Tags: javascript, html, css

Открыл для себя недавно details, очень удобный тег, чтобы делать аккордеоны, но никак не смог добиться от него плавного закрытия контента.
Хотел узнать, может кто смог реализовать плавное закрытие, а то резкое исчезновение контента очень плохо смотрится.
Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 0):

Например вот так можно

```
details[open] {
  animation: slide .3s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0%    { opacity: 0; transform:  translate(0, -10px); }
  100%  { opacity: 1; transform:  translate(0, 0); }
}
```

Comment: Вы дали неплохое решение, однако можно было и воспользоваться transition в таком случае. Но это не решение вопроса, вы анимируете весь элемент details с его элементом summary, при этом анимация выглядит будто весь элемент пропадает и снова появляется.

Comment: Это на открытие, как красиво открыть я знаю, есть много способов, а вот как красиво закрыть, это другой вопрос.

Comment: @ВалентинПавельчук Сорри, не вчитался в вопрос, сейчас разберемся :)

Answer (score -2):

Следующий код будет работать при открытии к сожалению я не смог сделать так чтобы после  закрытия но можно сделать используя WAAPI

```
details[open] summary + * {
  animation: slide .3s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: «я не смог сделать так чтобы после закрытия» — ну значит не является ответом